# Consume OpenTravel WSDL with php soap

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

how can I handle this code and consume OTA WSDL? The schema definition is http://schemas.liquid-technologies.com/OpenTravel/2008B/?page=http___www_opentravel_org_ota_2003_05.html

I tried this:

```
$client = new \SoapClient('myservice?wsdl', array(
        'trace'=>true
    ));
$data = [
'OTA_VehAvailRateRQ'=>[
    'POS'=>[
        'Source'=>[
            'RequestorID'=>[
                'ID'=>'myID',
                'MessagePassword'=>'myPASSWORD'
            ]   
        ]   
    ],
    'VehAvailRQCore'=>[
        'VehRentalCore'=>[
            'PickUpDateTime'=>'2018-05-25T08:30:00+00:00',
            'ReturnDateTime'=>'2018-05-26T08:30:00+00:00',
            'PickUpLocation'=>[
                'LocationCode'=>'CODE',
            ],
            'ReturnLocation'=>[
                'LocationCode'=>'CODE',
            ]                   
        ]   
    ]
]
];
$result = $client->__soapCall('OTA_VehAvailRate', $data);
```

and get this xml, where item, key and value are wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:OTA_VehAvailRateRQ>
    <ns1:POS>
        <ns1:Source>
            <item>
                <key>RequestorID</key>
                <value>
                    <item>
                        <key>ID</key>
                        <value>bookingservice</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <key>MessagePassword</key>
                        <value>123booking</value>
                    </item>
                </value>
            </item>
        </ns1:Source>
    </ns1:POS>
    <ns1:VehAvailRQCore>
        <ns1:VehRentalCore PickUpDateTime="2018-05-25T08:30:00+00:00" ReturnDateTime="2018-05-26T08:30:00+00:00">
            <ns1:PickUpLocation/>
            <ns1:ReturnLocation/>
        </ns1:VehRentalCore>
    </ns1:VehAvailRQCore>
</ns1:OTA_VehAvailRateRQ>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Thanks!

---

First edit:

Nope, maybe my wsdl definition is not correct. I tried also with this:

```
$data = '<OTA_VehAvailRateRQ>
     <POS>
        <Source>
           <RequestorID ID="myID" MessagePassword="myPASSWORD">
              <CompanyName>WEB001</CompanyName>
           </RequestorID>
        </Source>
     </POS>
     <VehAvailRQCore>
        <VehRentalCore PickUpDateTime="2018-05-25T08:30:00+00:00" ReturnDateTime="2018-05-26T08:30:00+00:00">
           <PickUpLocation LocationCode="APR" />
           <ReturnLocation LocationCode="APR" />
        </VehRentalCore>
     </VehAvailRQCore>
  </OTA_VehAvailRateRQ>';

$soapBody = new \SoapVar($data, \XSD_ANYXML, null, 'http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05');
$result = $client->__soapCall('OTA_VehAvailRate', [$soapBody]);
```

but this is the response

```
Cannot find dispatch method for {}OTA_VehAvailRateRQ
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing (too hard for me to test) that it misbehaves because, according the the schema, `RequestorID` has neither an attribute nor a child element named `ID`.  Try this ...

```
$data = [
'OTA_VehAvailRateRQ'=>[
    'POS'=>[
        'Source'=>[
            'RequestorID'=>[
                '_'=>'myID',
                'MessagePassword'=>'myPASSWORD'
            ]   
        ]   
    ],
    ...
```

`_` must be the first element in the array.  I think this should give:

```
<RequestorID MessagePassword="myPASSWORD">myID</RequestorID>
```

Comment: Nope, maybe my wsdl definition is not correct, I've edited my post with new code.

Comment: Hi Paul, where or how can I can get the OpenTravel WSDLs? Can you perhaps point me in the right direction

Comment: I'm also looking for OpenTravel WSDL, not sure where we should get these... thanks!